# Apple app rejected - two SQLite .db files are downloaded to /Library/Caches/file_0/

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, cordova, caching

I am trying to publish my application to the Apple App Store, but it has since been rejected due to the following reason:

```
two SQLite .db files are downloaded to /Library/Caches/file_0/
```

The application is built in Cordova and uses SQLite. I cannot figure out why the app is getting rejected.

Is there anyone who has had a similar problem with an application?

If so, how did you get around this? Is there a way to stop the application from caching the db files like that, something in xcode perhaps?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The application downloads data from a server upon opening. The data is Javascript and html, there is some database management stuff with the code downloaded, but I have another app which does the same thing on the store already and that passed certification.

> Apples Rejection Reply:

```
During review our team found this app downloads two SQLite files which dynamically alter the content and data of this binary. Please refer to the PLA, specficially 3.3.2.
```

Comment: post the full rejection text, with given Apple guidelines where it points to

Comment: Looks like that goes against their rules, if you have another app doing that probably they missed it during review.

Comment: If you are using any plugin, report this to the plugin author

Comment: No I am not, i am trying other options. If I figure it out ill post the answer